# SLO with SAML 2.0 (SP initiated SLO or IDP initiated SLO), which one is good to have in service provider

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

We created a application (SP), which have a option to login via **SSO**(Single Sign On) using third party application (any IdP).  We used **SAML 2.0** complaint for SSO(Single Sign On).

Question :

1. Which one is good to have in my application (SP initiated SLO or IDP initiated SLO)?
2. How many application using SP initiated slo and IDP initiated slo?
   (1 or 2 application(SP) name for each which are integrated with third party app)
3. How about creating both and keeping SLO is optional to IDP?

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no requirement to provide SLO. Many large service providers do not (Google Apps and Salesforce, for example).

If you're going to provide for it, *it's my opinion* that you should support both, but not require it of the SP (make it an option within your SP). All enterprise implementations (PingFederate, OAM, Siteminder, etc.) that I am aware of support both, but do not require either, on both SP and IdP sides.

Comment: thanks Andrew for your comments,  i need one more information, i created application such way that, when user enter URL (https://test.com) in browser we are redirecting seamlessly to IDP(without sso button).  We have a problem in logout option, after logout action we are showing 'successfully logout' message in login page with sso button. If user opened same app in other tab before logout action and if user refresh that page (after logout action in other tab) then we are redirecting seamlessly to idp. I am not sure this make sense to customer so can you give me any suggestion.

Comment: I'd say that if the customer clicked the logout button in one tab, and expected a refresh to work without a new SSO process taking place, then there should be some customer education. There's nothing in SAML to help out with this.